# Airflow with mysql rabbitmq-server Could not translate host name "postgres" to address: No address associated with hostname

Tags: mysql, rabbitmq, airflow

I'm trying to run an airflowjob scheduler with a mysql database and a rabbitmq-server.
Everything worked before i changed database.

I changed the `airflow.cfg` file to:

```
executor = CeleryExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
broker_url = amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/
```

After creating osme databases with mysql (I followed [this guide)](https://medium.com/@srivathsankr7/apache-airflow-a-practical-guide-5164ff19d18b)

But When I run `airflow scheduler` I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

Any ideas of what to try?

edit; More info about my settings:
I made the database with the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
mysql> create user 'airflow'@'localhost' identified by 'airflow';
mysql> grant all privileges on * . * to 'airflow'@'localhost';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: "Everything worked before i changed database."  How did you change the database?  From what?  To what?

Comment: Sorry! I changed to Mysql from SQLite.

Comment: But the config you showed us doesn't say anything about sqlite.

Comment: No because it's no longer used? I updated with some more information about how I stated the database for airflow to use. What else should I post? I'm a huge mysql noob

Comment: What's your Airflow version ? Have you read [this official doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-mysql-database) ? Have you run `airflow db init` ?

Comment: Looks like you tried many databases where postgres is one of them. so your database setup might be a bit messed up. Anyway, for the case that the setup might be cached somehow, don't forget to delete the cache after a database-change; I don't know if any cache is used at all, it's just a very general hint.